# What is Data Transfer Out in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am planning to use Amazon S3 for storing images for my upcoming project - I have one doubt on 'Data Transfer Out' prices.

What does this mean? It's written that you have to pay the charges of data transfer if you transfer data from S3 bucket to 'the public internet' - does this mean if I make my image public, (so I can share it's URL to everyone) it would count it as Data Transfer out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes You will be charged for the amount of data that is transfered out from the bucket to the internet.

If you look into the 1st question of Billing section of https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/ this page. You can see the example given there for how you will be charged for the amount of data transfered.

Comment: Thanks, it helps - but my particular question was what does 'transfer from the bucket to the internet' mean? Does it mean if I make my image public, and anyone views it through the link, it would count as 'Data Transfer Out'? Thanks again!

Comment: S3 transfer out means you will be charged for amout of data transfered out from S3 to internet. When you make object public, S3 makes that object available to internet. So every request to S3 for that object will result in transfer of that object out to internet. So for single object , you will be charged for number of requests times the size of that object(in your case the image).

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are two concepts Data Transfer and Requests, I think here you are talking about the Requests and not about Data Transfer, in Requests, they count for every time that someone clicks your webpage and request to show the image, or download it.

Look at this information below :

> **AWS S3 REQUESTS PRICING**
>
> **PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST**  $0.005 / 1,000 requests $0.01 / 1,000 requests
>
> **GET and all other requests**    $0.004 / 10,000 requests    $0.01 / 10,000 requests

Look at what AWS says about the requests:

You pay for requests made against your S3 buckets and objects. S3 request costs are based on the request type, and are charged on the quantity of requests as listed in the table below. When you use the Amazon S3 console to browse your storage, you incur charges for GET, LIST, and other requests that are made to facilitate browsing. Charges are accrued at the same rate as requests that are made using the API/SDK. Reference the S3 developer guide for technical details on the following request types: PUT, COPY, POST, LIST, GET, SELECT, Lifecycle Transition, and Data Retrievals. DELETE and CANCEL requests are free.

LIST requests for any storage class are charged at the same rate as S3 Standard PUT, COPY, and POST requests.

You pay for retrieving objects that are stored in S3 Standard – Infrequent Access, S3 One Zone – Infrequent Access, S3 Glacier, and S3 Glacier Deep Archive storage. Reference the S3 developer guide for technical details on Data Retrievals.

**Now look at the concept of TRANSFERS:**

You pay for all bandwidth into and out of Amazon S3, except for the following:

- Data transferred in from the internet.
- Data transferred out to an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)
  instance, when the instance is in the same AWS Region as the S3
  bucket.
- Data transferred out to Amazon CloudFront (CloudFront).

The pricing below is based on data transferred "in" and "out" of Amazon S3 (over the public Internet)†††. Transfers between S3 buckets or from Amazon S3 to any service(s) within the same AWS Region are free. You also pay a fee for any data transferred using Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration. Learn more about AWS Direct Connect pricing.

If you want more info go [AWS Princing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)